# VideoProgressIndicator() can't be clicked if it's inside the Align class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Supposed to be when VideoProgressIndicator() is clicked the time of the video will also be changed but when I put it inside Align..it won't work anymore.

```
Widget _buildPlay() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _vidController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: VideoPlayer(_vidController),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(1.1, 1.),
                  child: VideoProgressIndicator(
                    _vidController,
                    this.allowScrubbing,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  ),
                ),
             ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

but if I put it inside an Expanded it will work but no alignment anymore.

```
Widget _buildPlay() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _vidController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: VideoPlayer(_vidController),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: VideoProgressIndicator(
                    _vidController,
                    this.allowScrubbing,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  ),
                ),
             ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```